# My program seems to be working with everything as a check digit EXCEPT 0 which will return invalid even if its valid?

Tags: python

For example entering `0-7487-4459-2` would return valid, which it should but `1-841-46202-0` returns invalid even though its valid??? I don't really know what to do but I've tested to see what `11 % 11` is and its 0 so `0 == 0`should return True and therefore valid?? I'm really stuck with this one

```
while True:  # infinite loop until quit
answer = input("Enter ISBN or enter q to quit")  # enter number
if answer == "q" or answer == "Q":  # quit
    exit()
else:
    isbn = answer
    temp = ""  # temporary
    answer = ""  # set as isbn and reset 'answer'
    for x in range(len(isbn)):
        if ord(isbn[x]) == 45:
            print("", end="")  # print nothing when dash
        else:
            temp += isbn[x]  # add new code to temp

    isbn = temp  # reset temp
    temp = ""

    # RUN CHECKS ON ISBN
    if (len(isbn)) == 10:
        print("", end="")
    else:  # check length
        print("Incorrect length for isbn")
        exit()

    # CHECK DIGITS
    if isbn.isdigit() == True:
        print("", end="")
    else:
        print("Non number detected")
        exit()

    print(isbn)
    check = (isbn[len(isbn) - 1])  # add the last digit as check
    isbn = isbn[:-1]  # remove last digit as its check

    total = 0
    multi = 10
    for x in range(len(isbn)):
        temp = int(isbn[x])  # set it as int
        total += (temp * multi)  # times by multiplier and add to total
        multi -= 1  # take one

    answer = (11 - (total % 11))
    print(answer)  # modulo 11
    print(check)
    if int(check) == answer:  # check and print valid if valid

        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
Enter ISBN or enter q to quit1-841-46202-0
1841462020
11
0
Invalid
Enter ISBN or enter q to quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`answer = (11 - (total % 11))` can only produce results in the range 1 thru 11 inclusive, so nothing could possibly match a check digit of 0.  Try `answer = -total % 11`, which gives 0 when your original would give 11.

Either version can produce 10 as the answer, which cannot match a single decimal digit.  In fact, the ISBN check digit is a base-11 number, with that extra possible value being represented as 'X'.  You will need to add a special case to accept 'X' when the answer is 10 - without that, you will reject about 9% of all possible ISBNs.

Comment: OK thanks good answer both helped and its working with X,x and 0 now!

Answer (score 0):

You never execute an evaluation **11 % 11**.  You did the math for the entire number: total % 11.  The totals you have for these two items are 262 and 187.  The computation you do subtracts that from 11.  Ah ... *jasonharper* just posted that part.

You go through a lot of work to convert the rest of the ISBN to a number.  You can get rid of that with a simple statement:

```
total = int(isbn[:-1])
```